# How can I access the React router's location prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

I need to be able to access the `location` prop in the `App` component. I'm wondering if it's possible to get the `Router` component to pass its `history` prop to the child `App` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way will be to use the `withRouter` HOC.

It will pass `match, location, history` props to the wrapped component:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const App = ({ location }) => <div></div>;

export const AppWithRouter = withRouter(App);
```